# Eclipse - specific color/font replacing

Tags: eclipse, text, syntax, ide, format

I was messing around with colors and I changed this:

When the cursor is on a certain method, all similar methods are highlighted:

http://prntscr.com/jc0kzi

It changed to black color, I want it to go back to the default of white.

Where is this option in here:

http://prntscr.com/jc0jyf

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely the `Occurrences` values on the **Annotations** preference page.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-22.htm?cp=0_4_1_1

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Occurrences

And change the color according to your requirement.